# Modal OK/Cancel-Style Dialogs

Tags: python, pyqt, arguments, pyqt4

I am part of the book
Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt - The Definitive Guide to PyQt Programming (2008)
I do not understand is that page 163-165

```
class NumberFormatDlg(QDialog):
    def __init__ (self, format, parent=None):
        super(NumberFormatDlg, self). __init__(parent)
...

form = NumberFormatDlg()
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a instance of the class `NumberFormatDlg`, its `__init__` method is called with the instance as first argument (`self`), plus any other arguments that are passed in.

The `NumberFormatDlg.__init__` method is defined with one *required* argument (`format`) and one *optional* argument (`parent`). Optional arguments will have a default value assigned to them if one is not given (e.g. `None` for `parent`), but required arguments *must* be explicitly given by the caller.

So `NumberFormatDlg` instances have to be created like this:

```
form = NumberFormatDlg(format_string)
```

or like this:

```
form = NumberFormatDlg(format_string, parent_widget)
```

Hopefully your book will tell you what `format_string` should be...